# Use factory to build singleton object

Tags: java, thread-safety, singleton

I'm trying to create some singleton object with a factory:

```
public class MyObjectFactory {
    private MyObject myObject;

    public MyObject getInstance(boolean newInstance) {
        if (newInstance) {
            // return new object
        } else {
            // return the old object
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the **getInstance(boolean newInstance)** method to generate a new object or reuse the existing singleton object.

if **newInstance is true**: I will generate a new singleton object

if **newInstance is false**: if myObject is null, then generate a new one and return, or if myObject is not null, just return it.

And this **getInstance(boolean newInstance)** must be thread safe. Any idea how?

Comment: If `newInstance` is `false`, which of the potentially many old objects should be returned? And how is that a Singleton at all?

Comment: @f1sh  can ignore the part that I call it as a singleton.  if you genrate a new one, the old one will be override

Answer (score 1):

This is not how Singletons work. The whole point of a Singleton is to have a **single instance across the program** of a certain class. Parameterizing your factory method to either get a new instance or a previous one does not fall into the definition of a Singleton.

Also, the best Singleton implementation is known as the `Bill Pugh Singleton`:

```
public class BillPughSingleton {

    private BillPughSingleton() {}

    public static BillPughSingleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class SingletonHelper {
        private static final BillPughSingleton INSTANCE = new BillPughSingleton();
    }
}
```

The William Pugh implementation ensures multi-thread safety and the best performances as the nested static class is loaded by the class loader only when the method `getInstance()` is invoked. In fact, a static nested class is simply a static member of the outer class (no difference from a static field or a static method in terms of creation time). The static member is created only when the class is used, so since no instances of the `BillPughSingleton` can be created with a constructor, a single thread-safe instance is generated only when the outer class is used via the `getInstance()` method.

##### EDIT

If what you're asking is something that either creates a new instance if this is null or returns/overrides the existing one. Then, what you need is not a singleton but a retriever class. Besides, you should also take into consideration in your design whether this retriever class will be used in multi-thread scenarios or not. Here is a basic implementation:

```
class MyRetriever {
    private static MyClass instance;

    //Private constructor to force the factory method invocation
    private MyRetriever() {}

    //Synchronizing the method in order to avoid race condition and establish a happens-before relationship between threads
    public synchronized static MyClass getInstance(boolean flagOverride) {
        if (flagOverride || instance == null){
            instance = new MyClass();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, now you can ignore the part that I call it as a singleton, the logic I want is: to use getInstance(boolean newInstance) function, and try to generate a new object or reuse the  existed object according the value of newInstance. if you genrate a new one, the old one will be override

Comment: @Liem I've updated the answer with a retriever (non-singleton) implementation of what you were asking for.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, this is one way to implement what you want:

```
public class MyObjectFactory {
   private volatile MyObject inst;
   public synchronized MyObject getInstance(boolean newInstance) {
     if(newInstance) {
       inst = new MyObject(...);
     }
     return inst;
   }
}
```

Making the field `volatile` means that the value is not cached in the CPU, so changes are immediately visible to all threads. Making the method `synchronized` ensures that only one thread can enter it at the same time.